# Subir imagen a Firebase usando la camara del telefono

Tags: android, firebase

Tengo un onActivityResult, con dos Case, uno para elegir una imagen de la Galeria, la muestra en la actividad y luego la sube a Firebase, hasta aqui todo correcto, luego el otro Case es para poder hacer una foto con la camara y la muestra, he intentado insertar el codigo para que tmb se suba esa foto de la camara a FireBase pero no funciona. Es diferente a lo que tengo puesto en el case de la Galeria??

**Codigo onActivityResult**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        switch (requestCode){
            case PHOTO_CODE:
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { mPath }, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned" + path + ":");
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> Uri = " + uri);
                    }
                });
                imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPath);
                foto.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
                break;
            case SELECT_PICTURE:
                Uri path2 = data.getData();
                //Codigo para subir la imagen a Firebase
                StorageReference filePath2 = mStorage.child("Fotos Aviso").child(path2.getLastPathSegment());
                filePath2.putFile(path2).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Toast.makeText(Fotos.this, "Se ha subido la foto a FireBase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                foto.setImageURI(path2);
                imageBitmap = drawableToBitmap(foto.getDrawable());
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo tengo un proyecto personal parecido y las fotos que hago con la cámara las subo con estos métodos. Espero que te sirvan.

```
@Override
    public void uploadPhotoToDeal(Bitmap photo, String dealId) {

        final String idImage = dealId.concat(".jpg");

        storageReference = FirebaseHelper.getStorageReference().child("image/" + idImage);

        final byte[] data = getImageCompressed(photo);

        UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putBytes(data);

        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                HashMap<String, Object> uriChildren = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                uriChildren.put("photo", idImage);

                myDealReference.updateChildren(uriChildren);

                post(DealDetailsEvent.onImageAdded, null, null);
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            }
        });
    }

    private byte[] getImageCompressed(Bitmap photo) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
```

Te dejo también el enlace al proyecto por si necesitas mirar algo más.

https://github.com/Davids89/PayMe/tree/develop/app/src/main/java/luque/david/payme/dealDetails